# javascript parse html code extract the sentence

Tags: javascript, recursion, dom

I have this code html or more long, around 100 line:

```
    <div id="translate">
           <div> <p>Web <b>dictaphone </b> is built using Thanks to Sole for the Oscilloscope code! English texts for 
                    beginners to practice reading and comprehension online and for free.</p> 
                    <p>Practicing your comprehension of <b>written English will</b> both improve your vocabulary and 
                    understanding of <span class="term-highlight">grammar</span> and word order. The texts below are designed to help you develop while 
                    giving you an instant evaluation of your progress.</p>
                  <p>All test went wrong</p>
                  <p>Web application work CH<sub class="pippo">2</sub> M5 only with localhost</p>
            </div>
<div class="code">
              <span>
                beginners to practice reading and comprehension online and for free <b>dictaphone </b>.
              </span>
              <span class="term-highlight">grammar</span>
              <p>All test went wrong</p>
            </div>
</div>
```

i Parse this html with this code below:

```
let infoElementMT = document.getElementById('translate'); 

recurseDomChildren(infoElementMT, 'en');

    export function recurseDomChildren(start, langFrom)
    {
        var nodes;
        if(start.childNodes.length != 0)
        {
            nodes = start.childNodes;
            loopNodeChildren(nodes, langFrom);
        }
    }
    
    function loopNodeChildren(nodes, langFrom)
    {
        var node;
        for(var i=0;i<nodes.length;i++)
        {
          node = nodes[i];
    
            if(node.childNodes)
            {
                recurseDomChildren(node, langFrom);
            }
            if(node.nodeType === 3){
              console.log("NODE text", node)
              //outputNode(node, langFrom);
            }
        }
    }


The result i have it is :

ODE text "Web "
NODE text "dictaphone "
NODE text " is built using Thanks to Sole for the Oscilloscope code! English texts for beginners to practice reading and comprehension online and for free. Practicing your comprehension of "
NODE text "written English will"
NODE text " both improve your vocabulary and understanding of "
```

HOw can i have the results with the tag bold inside the sentence and not separate?

```
     NODE text: "Web <b>dictaphone</b> is built using Thanks to Sole for the Oscilloscope code! English texts for beginners to practice reading and comprehension online and for free.
    
     NODE text: Practicing your comprehension of <b>written English will</b> both improve your vocabulary and understanding of "

NODE text: beginners to practice reading and comprehension online and for free <b>dictaphone </b>.

NODE text: grammar
```

consider the fact that the html code is actually much longer so the code it must be recursive

Comment: So you are not just selecting the p tags? `Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("#translate p")).map(p => p.innerHTML.replace(/\s?\n\s+/g, ' '));`

Comment: No, I could also have a html of 100 lines, with only one id to tell me where i need to start to parse

Comment: No clue what you mean by that. Where to start to parse. Your code is selecting the children inside of that element. That is what the querySelectorAll is doing. It is selecting the paragraphs which are the lines. I am unsure what is different with the outout of that line of code versus what you want. Did you run it?

Comment: @epascarello i tested your example doesn't work for what i need, because the results it is with <span class=\"term-highlight\">grammar</span> inside, it must be considered as another node, and also you code work only with p tag but if i have 100 line of html or some span and div inside, doens't work.

Comment: @epascarello i add some other example

Comment: So many questions:  Do you want to fold in only the **b**old text?  What about **i**talic, **em**phaisized, or **strong**?  What about other inline tags?  What constitutes a `Node`?  What happened to both instances of `<p>All tests went wrong</p>` and `Web application work...`?

Comment: @Scott Sauyet   i ask the question if you have a solution i appreciate but if you have the question i think you need run the code

Comment: I'm not talking about your code, but your requirements.  You show the output you want to receive, but it's not clear how it relates to your input.

Comment: @Scott Sauyet I need to have a text sentence, cut when it is a tag ex: span or other but not cut when it is a tag b how i show on the two example

Comment: I guess my concern can be expressed this way: Is the sample correct output you gave exactly what you want to return when given your input?  If not, could you supply the corrected version?  If so, please explain why "All tests went wrong" isn't included.

Comment: @Scott Sauyet as i write below to "HOw can i have the results with the tag bold inside the sentence and not separate?" under it is the output i need

Answer (score 0):

(This is not really an answer, just a comment too long and too formatted to place in the comment box.  I plan on deleting this once requirements are established.)

I understand what you want to do with the `bold` tags.  My question is the rest of the requirements.  Here is a function that does exactly what you say you want, giving you the exact output you requested when you supply your input to the function.

```js
const convert = (input) => 
  `     NODE text: "Web <b>dictaphone</b> is built using Thanks to Sole for the Oscilloscope code! English texts for beginners to practice reading and comprehension online and for free.\n    \n     NODE text: Practicing your comprehension of <b>written English will</b> both improve your vocabulary and understanding of "\n\nNODE text: beginners to practice reading and comprehension online and for free <b>dictaphone </b>.\n\nNODE text: grammar    `


const input = `    <div id="translate">\n           <div> <p>Web <b>dictaphone </b> is built using Thanks to Sole for the Oscilloscope code! English texts for \n                    beginners to practice reading and comprehension online and for free.</p> \n                    <p>Practicing your comprehension of <b>written English will</b> both improve your vocabulary and \n                    understanding of <span class="term-highlight">grammar</span> and word order. The texts below are designed to help you develop while \n                    giving you an instant evaluation of your progress.</p>\n                  <p>All test went wrong</p>\n                  <p>Web application work CH<sub class="pippo">2</sub> M5 only with localhost</p>\n            </div>\n<div class="code">\n              <span>\n                beginners to practice reading and comprehension online and for free <b>dictaphone </b>.\n              </span>\n              <span class="term-highlight">grammar</span>\n              <p>All test went wrong</p>\n            </div>\n</div>`

console .log (convert (input))
```

I know it's not what you want.  It gives you the same output no matter *what* input you supply; and that's the point: I'm trying to fully gather your requirements.  I'm guessing there might be a language barrier at play, but it is not clear to me how your given input turns into your requested output.  Why does this line from your input:

```html
                  <p>All test went wrong</p>
```

not show up in the output?  And the same with this one?:

```html
                  <p>Web application work CH<sub class="pippo">2</sub> M5 only with localhost</p>
```

and a little further down, this one?:

```html
              <p>All test went wrong</p>
```

So it's quite clear that you want to keep the bold tag intact in the output string, but it's not clear what else you're trying to do.  As far as I can tell, your requested output is only slightly related to your input.  If both are correct, then you need to explain what should happen to the missing nodes.